Why didn't Walter go with Skyler to Hank's house for safety?
In Breaking Bad S04E12 "End Times", Walter doesn't go to Hank's house for safety together with Skyler.
In the previous episode, after he brought Walt to the desert, Gus threatens to kill Walt and his whole family if Walt warns Hank about his plan of disposing of Hank, which Walt did. Now both Walt's and his family's lives are on the line.
Why doesn't Walt go with Skyler to the safe place, instead of staying at home to die alone? This doesn't seem to benefit his family in any way, since Gus is targeting them all.

Who is the "he" who makes sure he's gonna kill Walt? That sort of detail is required to properly answer a question (and might be the cause of the downvote). Can you please [edit] that in? IIRC, Walt explains it to Skylar in advance, right?

okay , I edit it ... I didn't notice I forgot to add his name in What I'm asking is Gus warn walt he will kill his wife , his son and his infant daughter if walt warn hank , which he did , so now gus is coming for both walt and the rest of his family so I don't see why walt would stay alone in his house instead of going with skylar to hank house where the DEA is , both their lives are on the line now so why would walt think him dying alone would do any good for his family ?

Walt has no freedom to operate in Hank's house
Throughout the show, Walt egotistically believes that he can out-think and out-smart anyone. When faced with a problem he believes he can come up with the best solution and execute it. He rarely listens to advice, even from characters like Mike who have been in this world for much longer than him.
Not going to Hank's house is completely in character:

He rightly thinks that he is the primary target of Gus's ire
His family are safer at Hank's and without him
He has complete freedom to operate, come up with a plan and do something when he is not with Hank and his family.

